# with the Bootstrap Table plugin, how to set a search string on first load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

With the Bootstrap Table plugin (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) how to set a search string when the table is loaded for the first time?

Exists only a "data-search" attribute to enable the search input, but this doesn't valorize it.

I looked for a "data-search-text" attribute but I've not found it.

Comment: Why not set the value and trigger an event with jquery on load/$(function?

Comment: due to html markup hardcoded in the plugin I can't access easly to the input element that is created at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't support for data attribute but only via JavaScript

```
bootstrapTable({
    formatSearch: function () {
        return 'search string';
    }
});
```

Comment: this code set only the default input value but any edit in the input will be reset

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is this one:

```
var srch_str = 'your search string';
var bstable_first_load = true;
table.on('post-body.bs.table', function () {//when the table is loaded the first time and visible in the DOM, set the search string...
    if(srch_str.length > 0 && bstable_first_load){$('.fixed-table-toolbar').find('.search > :input').val(srch_str);bstable_first_load = false};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed such a behavior too. My first attempts were to use `bootstrapTable('resetSearch', 'my-query')` with a fixed timeout; sadly this was yielding two requests (and additional reflows if the first query made it to the client) so it was sub-optimal.

After a while I found that the goal can be achieved modifying query params wisely (i.e. for the first request only):

```
var start_query = '20';

$('#table').bootstrapTable({
     queryParams: function(params){
        if(start_query){
            $('.bootstrap-table').find('.search input').val(start_query)
            params['search'] = start_query
            start_query = null
        }
        return params
    }
});
```

Interestingly the `$input.val()` call does **not** fire any additional callbacks so the code above uses only one query/request.

Please see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/15364/

Edit: The preferred way to do implement such behavior probably should use `searchText` option; sadly it also issues two requests. I created an issue in [bootstrap-table repo](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/3310).

Edit 2: A patch for two-request behaviour of `searchText` has been [merged](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/commit/5f1a46e9770a3e5224b80c2f0f73139c62d75e88) into the development branch of the Bootstrap Table plugin and should be a part of the next release.

Answer (score 0):

This script allows you to filter data in the table on the first load

```
<script>
 $('document').ready(function(){
   const table = $('#tableId').DataTable();
   table.search('what_you_looking_for').draw();
 });
</script>
```