# Bootstrap-Table Plugin, Filter by initial search value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Using the bootstrap-table plugin (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) I'm trying to set up a table that automatically searches for the default search value when the table loads.  I set the default value inside the javascript file, but it won't initiate the search unless you click in the search box and press any key.

I also tried creating a new javascript file to load after everything else, using some of the code recommended on this page ([with the Bootstrap Table plugin, how to set a search string on first load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028857/with-the-bootstrap-table-plugin-how-to-set-a-search-string-on-first-load)) and it sets the initial value, but has the same problem.  I'm trying to figure out how i can initialize the search without pressing a key.

```
var srch_str = 'v1.00';
var bstable_first_load = true;

$(document.getElementById('server_table')).on('load-success.bs.table',function () {//when the table is loaded the first time and visible, set the search string...
    if(srch_str.length > 0 && bstable_first_load){$('.fixed-table-toolbar').find('.search > :input').val(srch_str);
    bstable_first_load = false};
})
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Also I don't think it affects anything, but you're using Javascript's `document.getElementById()` with jQuery's `.on()` function. It just looks odd to me :P

Comment: No, it doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems they recently added this feature in the newest version with:

```
data-search-text="Your Search Query"
```